# php app files permission after docker build

Tags: apache, docker, file-permissions, dockerfile

I'm trying to build docker image with SuiteCRM using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.4-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    && apt-get install -y libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev mercurial zip nano \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && apt-get -y install re2c libmcrypt-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
    && apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get -y install libssl-dev libc-client2007e-dev libkrb5-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap mbstring json \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -k -L -o suitecrm.zip "https://suitecrm.com/component/dropfiles/?task=frontfile.download&id=35"
RUN unzip -q suitecrm.zip -d /var/www/
RUN rm suitecrm.zip
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html && mv /var/www/suitecrm-7.2.2-max /var/www/html
RUN rm -rf /var/www/suitecrm-7.2.2-max
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload config_override.php

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Then image built and ran I've got an errors:

```
Warning: include(include/MVC/preDispatch.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 42
...
```

File owner is www-data:www-data

```
$ docker exec -t suite_web_dev ls -la index.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 2525 Mar  2 18:04 index.php
$ docker exec -t suite_web_dev ls -la include/MVC/preDispatch.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 2766 Mar  2 18:04 include/MVC/preDispatch.php
```

If I exclude form Dockerfile lines where it downloading App and changing files permissions, and call these commands after image start, everything works fine.

```
RUN curl -k -L -o ...
...
RUN chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload config_override.php
```

What differens between changing permission at build and after run? What I need to do for build image with App code?

**Upd:**
docker runs under boot2docker:
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.7.1
Docker version 1.7.1

Comment: Maybe one of the commands are not being found in the path? try specifying their full path, specially for curl or unzip

Comment: All of these commands have done correctly at build process. All files at their places with permission conform to an executed commands (chown, chmod).

But, I don't know why, this permission unacceptable for apache.

Comment: does the container exit or stay running?

Comment: After built and ran I connect to the container via docker exec -t [container_name] [command]. All checks were made at running container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission does not seem to be on a file, but on 'open stream' operation. 
This could be one of the causes:

When you install your application in the docker file, the hostname of the final container will no longer be the same as the hostname of the temporary container used while building the image. The app installer might fetch the hostname and store it in some configuration file.

If that is the case, then, when you run the container, you should execute a script which replaces the hostname in the config.

Comment: Thank you for help. Problem was solve by join all file operations into one command.


`RUN unzip -q suitecrm.zip -d /var/www/ \
 && rm suitecrm.zip \
 && rm -rf /var/www/html \
 && mv /var/www/suitecrm-7.2.2-max /var/www/html \
 && rm -rf /var/www/suitecrm-7.2.2-max \
 && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
 && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html \
 && cd /var/www/html \
 && chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload config_override.php`

Comment: As I can see, these commands executing at the same temporary container so it solve the problem.